# jQuery find next not working with a div structure

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi created a div structure and which will allow users to insert multiple office numbers and addresses that are related to each. i.e Office One, Office Two etc.

I slidetoggle between these sections. I have 8 phone numbers and I use jQuery to hide ones that are not ticked and by clicking "add new number" it will reveal the next number in the list.

However as this only works on the section named office one and not office two. If you are able to click on add new number and test on office one and then office two you'll see the difference. When the add button is clicked it should also append a hide and clear link however this is not been appended.

My add function is as below or view my [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal/qMw44/)

```
$(".add").click(function () {
 $(this).closest('.togglesettings').find(".contact_numbers:hidden:first").fadeIn("slow", function () {
             $(this).find('.remove').remove();
                 $(this).find('.clearnumber').remove();
                 $(this).find('.contact_numbers .input_tel:last-child').append("<a href='#' class='remove'>Hide</a><a href='#' class='clearnumber'> Clear #</a>")
            });
    });
```

This however works when I use a table structure, click for that [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gutigrewal/6pcvk/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your add click handler, change:

```
$(this).closest('.togglesettings').find(...
```

to

```
$(this).closest('.form-group.container').find(...
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/qMw44/1/)**

Comment: ahh thanks, why is that the remove and clear button is not appearing which refers to this line `$(this).find('.contact_numbers .input_tel:last-child').append("<a href='#' class='remove'>Hide</a><a href='#' class='clearnumber'> Clear #</a>")`

Comment: For two reasons. First $(this) refers to the div just added so it can't find `.contact_numbers`. Second, you can't append a link to an input. You might want to use `.after()` instead like ` $(this).find('.input_tel').after("<a href='#' class='remove'>Hide</a><a href='#' class='clearnumber'> Clear #</a>")`. See http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/3asKP/

Answer (score 0):

.togglesettings wrap up the two phone lists, an after you get the first hidden (.contact_numbers:hidden:first), so you get an phone from the first list (until all of them are not hidden). So changes:

```
$(this).closest('.togglesettings').find(...
```

for something like

```
$(this).closest('.ten.columns').find(...
```